How to read pdf form fields smalot/pdfparser?
I am trying to read data from pdf and save into separate columns(Name,Address,Email,Company) but the smalot/pdfparser returning output as string
$parser = new \Smalot\PdfParser\Parser();
$pdf = $parser->parseFile('document.pdf');
$output= $pdf->getText();
echo $output;

output = Name:test Address:test 123 email:test@test.com company:abc
How can I convert this to an array like this
[
 'Name'=> 'test',
 'Address'=> 'test 123',
 'Email`=>`test@test.com',
 'Company'=>'ABC'
]

